# Highest Rank Number in an Array, Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

**Kata**: *Complete the method which returns the number which is most frequent in the given input array. If there is a tie for most frequent number, return the largest number among them.
Note: no empty arrays will be given.*

**My code**:

```
# to use mode()
import statistics

def highest_rank(arr):
    # mode is made into a list, in case multimodal
    mode = [statistics.mode(arr)]
    if len(mode) > 1:
        # able to use max() since mode is a list
        return max(mode)
    # if there is only one mode, it is the first item in the mode list
    return mode[0]
```

**My problem**:
"statistics.StatisticsError: no unique mode; found 2 equally common values"

**My question:** *Why won't my code return the max modal value when there are 2 equally common values?*

**Highest rank solution**:

```
from collections import Counter

def highest_rank(arr):
    if arr:
        c = Counter(arr)
        m = max(c.values())
        return max(k for k,v in c.items() if v==m)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Presumably, it was decided that whatever the original rationale was, it was undesirable behavior because this was changed in 3.8. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mode): _Changed in version 3.8: Now handles multimodal datasets by returning the first mode encountered. Formerly, it raised StatisticsError when more than one mode was found._ Regardless, I guess the only answer to your psychological question is "because that's the way it was designed" or "they thought it was a good idea at the time".

Comment: Your answer is implied by the error message: *by design*, the function returns this error if the mode is not unique.  This is also covered in the (now older version) documentation for the method.  Where are you confused on this point?

Comment: Also, please note that your posted code does *not* cause the problem you claim, as you do not call the function.  Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).